# I get an implementation of a PopUp using an interface. Is there a way I could hard code in some parameters?

Tags: c#

I have code that calls a dependency service to get access to a PopUp implementation in iOS and Android. It does it this way:

```
DependencyService.Get<IPopUp>().Popup("XYZ", "ABC",
            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpTitleColor"],
            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpMessageColor"],
            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpBackgroundColor"],
            (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpSeparatorColor"],
            (sen, args) => {
                DidShowFirstMessage = true;
            });

public interface IPopUp
{
    void Popup(string title,
        string message,
        Color titleColor,
        Color messageColor,
        Color popUpBackgroundColor,
        Color popUpSeparatorColor,
        EventHandler handler);
}

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PopupImplemention))]
namespace Japanese.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class PopupImplemention : IPopUp
    {
        public void Popup(string title,
            string message,
            Color titleColor,
            Color messageColor,
            Color popUpBackgroundColor,
            Color popUpSeparatorColor,
            EventHandler handler)
        {
```

Every time the PopUp is called it uses the same Color parameters. Is there a way without changing the PopupImplemention that I could call Popup like this:

```
DependencyService.Get<IPopUp>().Popup("XYZ", "ABC", (sen, args) => {
            DidShowFirstMessage = true;
});
```

As it's an interface I don't think I can hard code parameters so wondering how I could do this.

Comment: Create an extension method

Comment: You can try to use [optional method arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) for this, but use should specify the compile time constant as default value

Comment: And optional parameter must be defined at the end of the parameter list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```cs
public static void Popup(this IPopUp popup, string title, string message, EventHandler handler)
{
    popup.Popup(
        title,
        message, 
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpTitleColor"],
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpMessageColor"],
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpBackgroundColor"],
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpSeparatorColor"],   
        handler
    );
}
```